# Identifying a flag set and printing a message in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi all I am working on checking for certain cases in a large loop, with in this large loop is this statement:

```
%Center Dialouge
        timers_c = [start_dpc_sh_hi_timer_c, start_dpc_sh_lo_timer_c, start_ffm_sh_act_hi_timer_c,...
            start_ffm_sh_act_lo_timer_c, start_hpot_eff_loss_timer_c, start_lfpt_dpsh_timer_c,...
            start_pc_sh_time_c, start_post_tl_nl_c, start_pre_tl_nl_c, start_elec_lu_timer_c];
        if perf_case_c ~= -1
            for k = 1:10
                if iscellstr(timers_c(k)) == 1                    
                   perf_case_timer_c = timers_c{k};
                   timer_set_c = 1;
                end
            end
        end
```

To I identify the start time and the case type to be output in a dialogue message:

```
if timer_set_c == 1
pcase_c = msgbox([sprintf('%s'),perf_case_c,sprintf('\nMET:%s\n'),perf_case_timer_c],'PERFORMANCE CASE');
end
```

I can't get the if statement that determines which case has been determined to work. I am trying to use the change from -1 to a string somehow, but it doesn't quite work.

A minimal example would be 
%Assume all timers initialized as zero
%Assume case ~= -1 (is a char array, string
timers_c = [timer1, timer2, timer3 ]

```
if case ~= -1
   for k = 1:3
       if iscellstr(timer_c(k)) ==1
         case_time = timers(c{k});
         time_set_flag = 1 
       end
    end
end
```

...
and then outside of the loop would be the above msgbox

Comment: Have you tried to run your script or function line by line to see if every variable are in scope and if they have the correct values?

Comment: @m_power yes everything is working I just can't figure out a way to identify which value of the timers_c array becomes set to a string

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that shows your problem. I don't have time to decipher all your variable names.

Comment: Is your msgbox line situated in the same script or same function?

Comment: The message box is outside of the loop, in the same script